# Password validation reg exp

Tags: regex, passwords

I need a regular expression for a password to fulfill the following requirements:

- It must be at least 6 characters long
- There must be 1 numeric character
- The first and last character must be an alphabetic character
- No special characters

I've found some expressions that come close to this, but none that match what I need.
Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried this but it doesn't quite fit the bill:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$
```

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: Exactly 1 numeric character, or at least 1 numeric character?

Comment: @João maybe yo're right :) i think he means `atleast` :)

Comment: I copied this from a business requirements document. It must be a typo. They must mean at least one number

Comment: if you mean `atleast`, take Joao's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assert that a string has 6 or more characters:

  `(?=.{6,})`
- Assert that a string has at least 1 numeric character:

  `(?=.*\d)`
- Match an alphabetic character in the first and last position:

  `^[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]$`

Combining all of the above, yields the following final expression:

```
(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z]
```

Comment: it can possibly match with `a3335b`. and the OP asked for 1 numeric only.

Comment: Yes, it has 6 characters, 4 of them numeric, and the first and last one are alphabetic characters, which matches OP requirements.

Comment: this could be it if the user says `atleast 1` numeric is allowed :)

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo: You're right, let's see if OP clarifies that.

Comment: Thanks! This works to perfection.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
(?=.*\d)^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]{4,}[A-Za-z]$
```

or in the case that you want ONLY one numeric it would be this

```
(?=[^\d]*\d[^\d]*$)^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]{4,}[A-Za-z]$
```